# Using google-react-maps to loop through list of markers and infowindows

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I'm trying to loop through a list of locations and set both markers and infowindows on them in React using `google-react-maps`. Unfortunately, with my current code, no markers are showing up. The map itself is rendering though. When I break the markers out individual they appear. I don't see any errors in the console (there's one warning but it doesn't seem to be causing any real issues). Here's my code

```js
export class MapContainer extends Component {
  state = {
    showingInfoWindow: false, // hides or show the info
    activeMarker: {}, // shows the active marker upon click
    selectedPlace: {}, // shows InfoWindow to select place upon marker
    locations: [{
        lat: 10,
        lng: -100,
        name: "Test"
      },
      {
        lat: -10,
        lng: 100,
        name: "Test 2"
      }
    ]
  };

  onMarkerClick = (props, marker, e) =>
    this.setState({
      selectedPlace: props,
      activeMarker: marker,
      showingInfoWindow: true
    });

  onClose = props => {
    if (this.state.showingInfoWindow) {
      this.setState({
        showingInfoWindow: false,
        activeMarker: null
      });
    }
  };

  renderMarkers() {
    return this.state.locations.map((location, i) => {
      console.log("location: " + JSON.stringify(location.lat));
      return <Marker
      key = {
        i
      }
      onClick = {
        this.onMarkerClick
      }
      position = {
        {
          lat: location.lat,
          lng: location.lng
        }
      }
      name = {
        location.name
      }
      />
    })
  };

  renderInfoWindows() {
    return this.state.locations.map((location, i) => {
      return <InfoWindow
      key = {
        i
      }
      marker = {
        this.state.activeMarker
      }
      visible = {
        this.state.showingInfoWindow
      }
      onClose = {
          this.onClose
        } >
        <
        div >
        <
        h4 > {
          this.state.selectedPlace.name
        } < /h4> <
        /div> <
        /InfoWindow>
    })
  };

  render() {
    return ( <
      Map google = {
        this.props.google
      }
      zoom = {
        5
      }
      style = {
        mapStyles
      }
      initialCenter = {
        {
          lat: 30.267860,
          lng: -97.713200
        }
      } >
      <
      div > {
        this.renderMarkers()
      } < /div> <
      div > {
        this.renderInfoWindows()
      } < /div> <
      /Map>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map the data directly in the render. Here is a [code sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-marker-infowindow-4p1sfm?file=Map.js) and code snippet that shows how multiple coordinates from json data are being used in the marker and infowindow.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  InfoWindow
} from "react-google-maps";
import location from "./data.json";

class Map extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      locid: ""
    };
  }

  onMarkerClick = id => {
    this.setState({
      locid: id
    });
  };
  render() {
    const GoogleMapExample = withGoogleMap(props => (
      <GoogleMap
        defaultCenter={{ lat: 40.756795, lng: -73.954298 }}
        defaultZoom={13}
      >
        {location.map(loc => (
          <Marker
            position={{ lat: loc.lat, lng: loc.lng }}
            onClick={() => this.onMarkerClick(loc.id)}
          >
            {this.state.locid === loc.id && (
              <InfoWindow
                onCloseClick={this.props.handleCloseCall}
                options={{ maxWidth: 100 }}
              >
                <span>{loc.id}</span>
              </InfoWindow>
            )}
          </Marker>
        ))}
      </GoogleMap>
    ));

    return (
      <div>
        <GoogleMapExample
          containerElement={<div style={{ height: `500px`, width: "500px" }} />}
          mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Map;
```

Note: use your API key in the index.js file in the code sample to make it work.